# How to map DBSet entity frame work object to local model?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am using entity frame work Data base first approach, I am creating an web api. where I am need to return all attendee from DB.

I am creating a crude operation for getting all records. But not sure how to map DBSet object to local model?

```
public IList<Attendee> GetAttendees()
        {
            var model = _dbContext.tbl_Attendee.ToList<Attendee>();
            return model;
        }
```

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/clmVe.png)
[After Matt suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up74t.png)

Comment: Did you try putting only var model = _dbContext.tbl_Attendee.ToList(); ?

Comment: @Matt : in that case it says it can not convert object type from one to another.

Comment: Oh, I see now, Attendee is different than tbl_attendee object. I suggest using automapper. http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Lists-and-arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

So **tbl_Attendee** Entity is different from **Attendee** class ? if yes
then u have to convert IQueryable<tbl_Attendee> to List< Attendee >

to convert it use **[Select](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select)** function. it will transform ur tbl_Attendee to Attendee how ?

```
var model = _dbContext.tbl_Attendee.Select(input=>{
new Attendee {
id= input.id // just demo property may be u have different  
Name= input.Name // just demo property may be u have different  
//etc
}
}).toList()
```